# Is there a way to increase memory allocation for running jobs through "srun, sbatch, or salloc"?

Tags: slurm

I use srun, salloc, or sbatch with slurm when I want to execute my Job.

```
srun -p PALL --cpus-per-task=2 --mem=8G --pty --x11 ./my_job  --job-name=my_job_1
```

I don't know how much memory I should allocate for the first job.
There are times when memory allocation is insufficient during running, and I want to prevent it from being 'out of memory exit'

Is there a way to increase memory allocation for jobs running through slurm?

Comment: Beware that the ` --job-name=my_job_1` parameter is passed to `./my_job`, not to `srun`. It should appear before `./my_job` for it to be passed to `srun`.

Answer (score 1):

No, generally speaking, you cannot increase the amount of resources allocated to a running job (except some cases where nodes can be added from another job).

There is no easy way to know how much memory a specific experience will require. It depends mostly on the data that are consumed/produced.

Some tips:

- in Python, you can use `sys.getsizeof(object)` to get the size of an object in memory (e.g. a Panda data frame)
- you can also use a *memory profiler* such as https://pypi.org/project/memory-profiler/ to get an overview of the overall memory consumption of the script
- you can use the `top` command while the script is running and look at the `RSS` column while running in an interactive Slurm session, or on your laptop, or other machine where you can test the script
- you can use the `sacct` command to get the actual memory usage of the job afterwards and possibly use that information to better estimate future, similar-looking, jobs.

Answer (score 0):

In the example above, if you are getting a memory error, try increasing your `--mem` allocation to more than 8G.

If you are using **sbatch**: sbatch your_script.sh to run your script, add in it following line:

`#SBATCH --mem-per-cpu=<value bigger than you've requested before>`

If you are using **srun**: srun python3 your_script.py add this parameter like this:

`srun --mem-per-cpu=<value bigger than you've requested before> python3 your_script.py`

Comment: Like the text, I don't know how much memory to allocate for my first job.
Does memory allocation always depend on experience?